# jQuery.each() function in plain (vanilla) javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.fn.slideUpTransition = function() {
            return this.each(function() {
                var $el = $(this);
                $el.css("max-height", "0");
                $el.addClass("height-transition-hidden");
            });
        };
```

In jQuery, this.each will iterate over all the matching elements and then apply the function. Here **this** as a global object holds the class selectors of a div.

> jQuery.fn.init [div.custom-dropdown-body.height-transition,
>   prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1)]

**How can we achieve the same with pure javascript?**
I tried doing following but couldn't get as expected:

```
var obj = this;
for(var i=0; i< obj.length; i++){
  // codes
};
return this
```

Comment: `this` in plain Javascript will never be more than one element.

Comment: There are several ways to iterate over iterable objects, the key question here is: what is `this`?

Comment: @Barmar Unless you add to `Array.prototype` for instance: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/mv5oz7ke/

Comment: @ChrisG I'm assuming he's processing DOM elements, analogous to what jQuery is doing.

Comment: You can use a `for` loop over the results of `querySelectorAll()`, or you can use `forEach()` with it if you turn it into an array or call it using the prototype call/apply methods.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll(someselector).forEach(function(el) {   el.style.maxHeight=0); el.classList.add("height-transition-hidden");})`

Comment: Are you saying you want to use a "pure javascript loop" inside the jQuery method?  If so...... why?

Comment: @mplungjan i believe you have a typo at the end of your first operation.

Comment: Ok, then please show us the complete operation that you are doing to get to the point that you are trying to use the `this` in the non-jQuery situation.  (and the typo comment in my previous comment was directed at mplungjan.  Notice the @ reference).

Comment: What I'm saying is you need to update your "I tried doing..." snippet at the end of your question to be more complete in what you are doing.  It needs to show us the entire context of what you tried there.

Comment: @Taplar what typo?

Comment: The `)` after `maxHeight=0` @mplungjan

Answer (score 2):

Here's a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) based example for how `$.each` works:

```js
NodeList.prototype.each = function(fn) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    fn.apply(this[i], [i, this[i]]);
  }
  return this;
};

document.querySelectorAll("p").each(console.log).each(function(i) {
  this.textContent = i;
});
```

```html
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
```

(Using the same order of `index, element` that jQuery uses, as opposed to the JS convention of `element, index`!)

Edit: added binding of correct `this` for callback

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach  already exists

Comment: @Taplar I know, but it doesn't work in all browsers afaik. And the question is mostly about how to manually implement functions like that, isn't it?

Comment: I don't believe it's about how to manually implement it.  The user doesn't know how to do it in plain javascript at all.  They don't know the vanilla method(s) available to be used.

Comment: @Sparsh Why do you want to delete it?

Comment: @Sparsh The title is very good though, and my answer is the exact answer for the title. So chances are this Q will benefit other people, which is a) what SO is all about and b) the reason why you cannot delete it. I'd rather keep it tbh.